# Java application is taking long time compare than query browser to run the query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I am getting big time difference when I run same query in query browser and in my application.  The query browser it took only 2 seconds to run the query. But in my application it is taking 20 seconds.
Actually, I am handling 12L records. I am using sql server database and used native SQL(JDBC) API in my application. I mean natve statement and resultSet API to fetch the record. I copied my code pieces here.

Also, I used same query condition with same user.

```
//------------------------ COUNT QUERY ------------------------------------
//It is taking 2 seconds in query browser but in my application takes 17 seconds

    try {
         String executeQry = "select count(id) from temp where some condition";
          statement = m_jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(executeQry);
          resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
          while (resultSet.next()) {
             totalCount = resultSet.getInt(1);
          }
     } catch (Exception e) {
        //
    }

//------------------------ RESULTSET QUERY ------------------------------------ //It is taking 2 seconds in query browser but in my application takes 20 seconds

try {
       String executeQry = "select ID,NAME,... from temp where some condition"; //Used rownumber to limit.
       statement = m_jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(executeQry, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

      while (resultSet.next()) {
        //PROCESS THE RESULTSET
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
 //
```

Is there any mistake in my code to handle? or any logic I need to improve(Any Cache concept- Statement cache or ResultSet Cache). 
  Please suggest me what are items I need to be care while handling large data(Java Level)

Comment: Please format your code properly using the code tags. Thank you.

Comment: The trivial explanation would be that you are connected to different databases. Other possibility is that you use different user and / or session settings. To see it, preferably check the execution plan of both queries if there is a difference.

Comment: There might be less obvious differences like fetching all rows, while the query browser only fetches the data it displays, etc.

Comment: @Mark this is offen the case but not for `select count(*) ...` queries.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber you're right. I somehow assumed there was a group by in there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any comments in your query, remove them before executing the query.

I faced this issue recently and noticed that my query was having comments in it.
For eg.

```
String query ="Select count(id) from table where emp = :emp -- and dept = :dep";
```

Here the string value after **`--`** is comment. 
Because of presence of these types of comments my query was taking a lot of time while executing from Java whereas just few seconds from sql developer.

When I removed the comment, the query ran in no time, withing 2-3 seconds I got my result.

I know the post is old but I hope it helps other users.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, execution speed depend on the where condition. But you can try the below code after select keyword in your query to speed up the execution time:

```
/*+ Ordered */       -- Use this as it is after Select keyword and run.
```